# Error installing dotNet4.0 on Wine

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, software-installation, qemu

sorry if the solution is obvious but this is my first time working with Linux.

Backstory (just the reason why I do this): I have to code a Programm for school which has to run on a Raspberry Pi and I have to present in my class. I've done a small smart mirror program but i made it with C#, since this is the only language I used before, now I try to get it running with Wine running in QEMU.

So I want to install dotNet4.6.1, and on the winepage nearly all test results say i need to install 4.0, on my system over Wine but I can't get it working. I've tried different Wine versions (3.0-rc6 and 3.9) and also I've tried the manual installation and the installation over winetricks. When I try to install it manually I get the following error messages:

```
0009:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
0009:fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (3): stub
0009:fixme:clusapi:OpenCluster ((null)) stub!
0009:fixme:clusapi:ClusterOpenEnum (0xdeadbeef, 4) stub!
0009:fixme:clusapi:ClusterEnum (0xdeadbeef, 0, 0x33f8b0, 0x122890, 261) stub!
0009:fixme:clusapi:ClusterCloseEnum (0xdeadbeef) stub!
0009:fixme:clusapi:CloseCluster (0xdeadbeef) stub!
```

I have no clue where I have to look and google didn't helped me either. If I install it with Winetricks everything is getting executed correctly but in the middle then the same error messages appear and at the end it says :
dotnet40 install completed, but installed file /home/pi/inet/dosdevices/c:/windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/ngen.exe not found
I'm completely lost right now and don't know where to look anymore or what it could be.

Comment: If you want to program on a Pi (which is an ARM processor) forget WINE (which is an x86 program).

Comment: I got Wine running because its running in QEMU which emulates a x86 environment and I can install somethings but I can't get dotNet running

Comment: QEMU is not a Pi issue, but if your aim is to get a program which runs on a Pi you are wasting your time.

Comment: You might get more go out of either [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/) (`sudo apt-get install mono-complete`) or [dotnet core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) (look for ARM32 binaries in the SDK) for running C# code on Linux. Depends what your project will be doing.